# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java

I have as asyncTask, inside the DoInBackground method I call a DBHelper class that should return every row inside a SQLiteDB. But when the DBHelper class method to retrieve the values gets fired I get the error:

> 07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
>   07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238): Process: com.test.test, PID: 22238
>   07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>   07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>   07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>   07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>   07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void test.ItemFolderP.setId(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>   07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238):    at test.test.returnValues(testt.java:59)
>   07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238):    at test.test$GetFProducts.doInBackground(test.java:107)
>   07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238):    at test.test$GetFProducts.doInBackground(test.java:1)
>   07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>   07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   07-20 10:33:33.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22238):    ... 4 more

This is the code of the DBHelper:

```
public class DBHelper{  

    private ItemFolderP item; //here I declare my item
```

Here's the method for retrieving the values

```
public ItemFolderP returnValues(int index){

    Cursor mRow= database.rawQuery("select * from " + CM_TABLE + " LIMIT 0, 4", null);
    if (null!=mRow) {
        mRow.moveToNext();
        item.setId(Integer.toString(mRow.getInt(mRow.getColumnIndex("Id"))));
        item.setTitle(mRow.getString(mRow.getColumnIndex("test")));
        item.setCode(mRow.getString(mRow.getColumnIndex("code"))); 
        item.setPrice(mRow.getString(mRow.getColumnIndex("price")));
        item.setImageUrl(mRow.getString(mRow.getColumnIndex("url")));
    }

    return item;
}
```

And this is the item class:

```
public class ItemFolderP {
    public String id;
    public String title;
    public String codice;
    public String price;
    public String imageUrl;


public ItemFolderP(String id, String title, String codice, String price, String imageUrl) {
    super();
    this.title = title;
    this.id = id;
    this.price = price;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;

}

//titolo
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

//id
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

//codice
public String getCode() {
    return title;
}
public void setCode(String codice) {
    this.title = codice;
}

//image Url
public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}
public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

//id
public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

}
```

I feel the error might be caused by the fact that I haven't passed the context to the method but I can't understand how to fix it. Can someone help me?

Comment: If possible, don not post only the error message but the full stack trace. It also helps when you indicate the line in *your* code that raises the error. For you question: Where is `returnValues()` called from and when is `database` initialized (because it looks like it isn't initialized properly)?

Comment: @dhke I haven't posted the full DBHelper class code because It's not relevant for the error (the code works and the db is initialized fine), the error occurs as soon as I call the Item.setId() method. The method is called inside my async task DoInBackground method

Comment: @dhke I've posted the full stack trace! (I edited some names)

Comment: You seem to never assign a value to `item`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not giving `item` a value anywhere in the code, so it's always `null`. You should replace this block:

```
item.setId(Integer.toString(mRow.getInt(mRow.getColumnIndex("Id"))));
item.setTitle(mRow.getString(mRow.getColumnIndex("test")));
item.setCode(mRow.getString(mRow.getColumnIndex("code"))); 
item.setPrice(mRow.getString(mRow.getColumnIndex("price")));
item.setImageUrl(mRow.getString(mRow.getColumnIndex("url")));
```

with

```
item = new ItemFolderP(
    Integer.toString(mRow.getInt(mRow.getColumnIndex("Id"))),
    mRow.getString(mRow.getColumnIndex("test")),
    mRow.getString(mRow.getColumnIndex("code")),
    mRow.getString(mRow.getColumnIndex("price")),
    mRow.getString(mRow.getColumnIndex("url")));
```

Also, I don't think `item` should be a private field as it is only used within the `returnValues` method. A local variable will suffice.